# MySQL - Select Rows where Sum(rows) = something

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 Columns

```
detail_id, item_id, item_qty
```

I want to:

```
SELECT detail_id FROM tbl_details WHERE SUM(item_qty) = some value
```

I have tried to find answers here but failed, if someone can please provide a simple efficient query I will appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`.  Presumably you also need `GROUP BY`.  If this doesn't help, delete this question and ask another with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thank you. I have about 200 rows containing 1-20 qty each.Or should I edit the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try use **Having** clause

```
SELECT detail_id , SUM(item_qty)
FROM tbl_details 
GROUP BY detail_id 
HAVING SUM(item_qty) = some value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `WHERE` clause with aggregate function..use `Group BY & Having` ..[Reference Here](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/599/cannot-where-clause-with-aggregate-functions-like-having-sql). e.g...

```
SELECT detail_id , SUM(item_qty) total_item
FROM tbl_details 
GROUP BY detail_id 
HAVING total_item = some_value
```